# How can I find any non ASCII characters in Redshift database

Tags: regex, ascii, amazon-redshift

I've a database table I'd like to return all values where a column contains a non ASCII character anywhere in the string.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried this

```
select col_name,  regexp_instr(col_name,'[^[:ascii:]]') 
from test_table s
where created > sysdate - 1 
and regexp_instr(col_name,'[^[:ascii:]]') > 0 
limit 5;
```

but get this error:

```
error:  Invalid character class name, collating name, or character range.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '[^[:>>>HERE>>>ascii:]]'.
  code:      8002
  context:   T_regexp_init
  query:     5059536
  location:  funcs_expr.cpp:130
  process:   query20_31 [pid=7903]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to accomplish something similar recently but @BigDataKid's solution (writing `'[^\x00-\x7F]'` in the regex expression) won't work.
Usually, a backslash in combination with a literal character can create a regex token with a special meaning, in this case `\x` represents "the character whose hexadecimal value is" where `00` and `7F` are the hex values.
While Postgres supports it ([see 9.7.3.3. Regular Expression Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html)), it seems that Redshift's regex engine does not. You can check what exactly Redshift supports [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html).

The shortest and cleanest workaround I've found for this is:

```
SELECT column_name,
       CASE
           WHEN regexp_instr(column_name, '[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]') > 0 THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE END AS has_non_ascii_char
FROM table_name
WHERE has_non_ascii_char;
```

**Regex explanation:**
The outer brackets `[` , `]` (or a list if you will) is called "bracket expression", the caret (`^`) means negation, so `[^]` translates to "match any character not in the list".
In the list we have `[:print:]` and `[:cntrl:]` which are called "POSIX character class". `[:print:]` refers to any printable ASCII character (including space) and `[:cntrl:]` refers to all ASCII control characters (e.g. tab), together they should cover all ASCII characters.

Comment: RiskyMaor, what does `[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]` do?

Comment: @MarkDickerson I made an edit that added the explanation for the regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the range or characters you wish to use by looking at this table: http://unicode-table.com/en/ .

Look at the code below, where I filter based on a specific character range.

```
dev=# create table tb1 ( id integer, col1 varchar(10) , col2 varchar(10) ) distkey(id);
CREATE TABLE

dev=# insert into tb1 values (1, 'ABC', 'DEF');
INSERT 0 1

dev=# insert into tb1 select 1, chr(638), chr(640);
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into tb1 select 4, concat(concat('AB', chr(638)),'CD') , chr(640);                                                                                  
INSERT 0 1

dev=# select * from tb1;
 id | col1  | col2 
----+-------+------
  4 | ABɾCD | ʀ
  1 | ABC   | DEF
  1 | ɾ     | ʀ
(3 rows)

dev=# select id, col1,  regexp_instr(col1,'[^\x00-\x7F]') , col2,  regexp_instr(col2,'[^\x00-\x7F]')  from tb1;
 id | col1  | regexp_instr | col2 | regexp_instr 
----+-------+--------------+------+--------------
  4 | ABɾCD |            3 | ʀ    |            1
  1 | ABC   |            0 | DEF  |            0
  1 | ɾ     |            1 | ʀ    |            1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me along the way. I ended up with this (but for some reason it still does not seem to work, but I got what I needed anyway) 'select name2,  regexp_instr(name2,'[^(a-z|A-Z|0-9|\w|\s|\t)]'), count (*)
from reporting.data2 s
where created > sysdate - 1
and regexp_instr(name2,'[^(a-z|A-Z|0-9|\w|\s|\t)]') > 0 
group by artistname,  regexp_instr(name2,'[^(a-z|A-Z|0-9|\w|\s|\t)]')
order by count (*) desc'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(column_name, '[^'||chr(32)||'-'||chr(126)||']','') 
FROM table_name 
WHERE regexp_count(column_name, '[^'||chr(32)||'- '||chr(126)||']')> 0
```

Perhaps it will be useful to someone and
https://www.asciitable.com/