# search for emojis in redshift db

Tags: unicode, emoji

Our redshift db stores certain characters as a box when there isn't an equivlent character to render them, or at least razorSQL can't render them in the results.

What I'm trying to do is search a table for any instance of an emoji and either have them render in the results or with their corresponding unicode.  Apparently stackoverflow can't handle what the code looks like in razorSQL but the `?` it is basically a box.

The results from the query below get me everything that's a special character, be it an accented vowel in Spanish, chinese text, or an emoji.  RazorSQL can't display the emojis in their results pane, or if they can, I don't know how.

```
select * from messages
where body like '%?%'
and date >=getdate()-10
limit 100
```

This query doesn't return any results, the code is for it'd let me search for a smiley-face emoji

```
select * from messages
where body like '%U+1F603%'
and date >=getdate()-10
limit 100
```

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375454/how-can-i-find-any-non-ascii-characters-in-redshift-database) regarding how to find all instances of unicode, but this doesn't quite limit it to just the emojis.

Any ideas/thoughts on how to find emojis in text conversations as well as specifiy which emojis I'd want?